# Can Excel VBA call Macro in Different Macro Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

Can VBA code in an excel spreadsheet call a different XLSM Workbook file's Macro?

I have a local XLSM that needs to call a method in a different XLSM file, how can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open file workbook, close if already open

```
codeWorkBookPath = "Directory\"
codeWorkBookName = "file.xlsm"
codeWorkBookFullPathName = UCase(Trim(codeWorkBookPath)) &         
UCase(Trim(codeWorkBookName))
codeWorkbookAlreadyOpen = CommonWorkbook.isWbOpen(codeWorkBookName)
If Not codeWorkbookAlreadyOpen Then
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=codeWorkBookFullPathName, UpdateLinks:=False, 
 ReadOnly:=True
End If
```

activate the starting spreadsheet

```
Workbooks(startWorkBook).Activate
Sheets(startWorkSheet).Activate
```

Run the macroName

```
argString = "'" & Trim(codeWorkBookName) & "'!" & Trim(macroName)
APPLICATION.Run argString
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the sheet's CODENAME, not the name.

In the image I share, you should used "Sheet1", not "testSheet"

[image: Click to see]

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

**If both, Source & Target Workbooks are open then you can use any of the followings.**

*You may dynamically assign the Workbook & Macro name to variables, then you need to write this code.*

`Application.Run ("'" & workbookname &  "'!macroname")`

**N.B.** *Where `workbookname` is variable contains `File Path, Workbook & Sheet Name` & `macroname` contains the `Macro's Name`.*

Below is straight forward command:

`Application.Run ("'Test7A.xlsm'!Sheet1.Rangetest")`

**Option 2:**

**If the source Workbook is closed, then you need to use this method.**

```
Sub myMacro()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks("Test7A.xlsm")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test7A.xlsm")
    Run "Test7A.xlsm!Sheet1.RangeTest"
    wb.Close False
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

*Where `Test7A.xlsm` is Workbook name `Sheet1` is the Sheet name & `RangeTest` is the Macro you are calling from.*